# Android Listview clicking on name and then it displays an image

Tags: java, android, listview

Hi I have a created a listview of different countries and want to display and image once the country has been clicked on. I am using the following method:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id)
```

I am not sure what to put inside the method?

Comment: how you want to show the image..in a new activity or imageview?

Comment: I want to show the image in a new activity

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
 Toast ImageToast = new Toast(getBaseContext());
 LinearLayout toastLayout = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext()); 
 ImageView image = new ImageView() // get Item position;
 toastLayout.addView(image);
 ImageToast.setView(toastLayout);
 ImageToast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
 ImageToast.show();
```